# Send nested objects to asp.net core Get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following model objects

```
[DataContract]
public class Filter
{
    [DataMember (Name ="start")]
    public int Start { get; set; }

    [DataMember (Name="rows")]
    public int Rows { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "geoloc")]
    public GeoLocationModel GeoLocation { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class GeoLocationModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lng")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

and the following action

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task GetCities([FromQuery]Models.Filters.Filter filters)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

When I call my action with the following query (query generated by axios):

```
   /api/cities/?start=0&rows=5&geoloc=%7B%22lat%22:44,%22lng%22:3%7D
```

Parameters Start and Rows are filled correctly but GeoLoc is null.

How do I need to format my query to satisfy `FromQuery` Attribute?

Comment: Why dont you use POST ?

Comment: I also would suggest post but as an add-on you could set a hidden field with the JSON value of your complex model and post it back as a string. On your controller action just have a string parameter, get the JSON and deserialize it.

Comment: Try `/api/cities/?start=0&rows=5&geoloc.lat=44&geoloc.long=3`

Comment: @TonyNgo I know I could use a POST, but it's a query to retrieve objects without modify them so it should be a GET

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I already tried, it doesn't work

Comment: @Rémy there's no convention on how even arrays are sent as query parameters, much less complex objects. The URL's syntax is specific to Axios and I think, Ruby. If you insist on using that syntax you can create your own binding code. Another option would be to create a GraphQL/OData endpoint and call it with Axios. This way you'd use a standardized query syntax that can be called from more than one client

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know why you are talking about arrays, because I have no arrays in my models !
I finally created my own ModelBinder because no other choices.

Comment: @Rémy I'm talking about arrays because it's a far more common case where there's no convention on how to send them as URL query parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You could try url like:`/api/cities?start=4&rows=5&geoloc.Latitude=4&geoloc.Longitude=3`

Comment: It doesn't work
But it works if I use /api/cities?start=4&rows=5&geolocation.Latitude=4&geolocation.Longitude=3

It means that FromQueryAttribute doesn't take in account DataMember attributes :(

Comment: Yes.Did you change the model?Actually your property name is geoloc not geolocation in your question.

Comment: oh sorry for the mistake, my property name is GeoLocation

Comment: So this thread seems to be resolved.If you really want to use DataMember attributes,I suggest that you could mark this thread to close it and ask a new thread with posting necessary code.

Comment: This is not completly resolved because I would like to use my datamember names.